# Render a PPTX in browser (2018)

Tags: powerpoint

How can you render a `.pptx` in the browser?

In ~2016, Microsoft changed the format of its files to be XML. The XML is well defined, and I'm wondering if anyone has created a viewer yet. I haven't come across one.

Answer (score 0):

The format of MS Office files changed as of the release of Office 2007. The files are actually ZIP files that contain XML and other data.

There's a free online viewer described here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/

One important point: anyone who visits the link to your presentation can download it. That may be a plus or a huge minus, depending on your intent.